# Multiple tuples as input in a pig UDF written in Java

Tags: java, apache-pig, udf, pig-udf

Example output from pig script:

```
(1, 10)
(2, 100)
(3,44)
(4,99)
```

I eventually want to create a histogram in my java UDF. How can I input all of this at once in my UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple tuples as input to a UDF only work if you put the tuples in a bag and then use that as input. Easiest way is to do a group and then use the resulting bags as input for the UDF.